# Merging Tables in Apache Arrow

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

I have two `arrow:Table`s where table 1 is:

```
colA        colB
1           2
3           4
```

and table 2 is,

```
colC        colD
i           j
k           l
```

where both table 1 and 2 have the *same* number of rows. I would like to join them side-by-side as

```
colA        colB        colC        coldD
1           2           i           j
3           4           k           l
```

I'm trying to use `arrow::ConcatenateTables` as follows, but I'm getting a bunch of nulls in my output (not shown)

```
t1 = ... \\ std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table>
t2 = ... \\ std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table>
arrow::ConcatenateTablesOptions options;
options.unify_schemas = true;
options.field_merge_options.promote_nullability = true;
auto merged = arrow::ConcatenateTables({t1, t2}, options);
```

How do I obtain the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arrow::ConcatenateTables` only does row-wise concatenation.  There is no builtin helper method for column-wise concatenation but it is easy enough to create one yourself (apologies if this is not quite right, I'm not in front of a compiler at the moment):

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> CombineTables(const Table& left, const Table& right) {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::ChunkedArray>> columns = left.columns();
  const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::ChunkedArray>>& right_columns = right.columns();
  columns.insert(columns.end(), right_columns.begin(), right_columns.end());

  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>> fields = left.fields();
  const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>>& right_fields = right.fields();
  fields.insert(fields.end(), right_fields.begin(), right_fields.end());

  return arrow::Table::Make(arrow::schema(std::move(fields)), std::move(columns));
}
```